# How to wait for a dispatch action to be completed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to wait for a dispatch action to complete but I am not able to at the moment.
basically, I am trying to delete an array of documents in firestore. But I want to wait for each async function to be finished before executing the next function in the for loop, but I am not able to return a promise from my async function.
How can I wait for each function to finish so that next function can be executed only then

I have tried returning an async code using await but did not succeed

**The code for executing the program**

```
for(let i=0;i<this.state.createdAtList.length;i++){
await this.props.UserDataDelete(this.state.createdAtList[i],  uniq[i], this.state.toDel[i], email)
}
```

**UserDataDelete** function

```
export const UserDataDelete = (createdAt, DocumentsId, SessionId, email) => {

  return async(dispatch,  getState, {getFirestore}) => {


return await Promise.all([  firestore.collection('hello').doc(email).collection('sessions').doc(SessionId).delete().then(()=> {
  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_USER_COLLECTION_SUCCESS' });
}).catch(err => {
  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_USER_COLLECTION_ERROR' }, err);

})
,
 firestore.collection('hello').doc(email).collection('documents').doc(DocumentsId).delete().then(()=> {
  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_USER_SUCCESS' });
}).catch(err => {
  dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_USER_ERROR' }, err);

})
,

      storage().ref(`hello/${email}/${createdAt}`).delete().then(()=> {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_USER_DATA_SUCCESS' });
      }).catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_USER_DATA_ERROR' }, err);
      })])

return true

  }
};
```

I am returning from a promise.all() but it does not wait, I am using await keyword in the async program but it does not return a promise,
so promise.all() does not wait, despite using await on the command and then returning it.
How can I make this promise.all() statement return a promise to my code where the function is closed. so that the calling function waits till the promise.all() is completed.
I want this promise.all() statement to return a promise value to the code where it is called so that I can use await to stop code execution till the current function is finished

I want the function in the for loop to execute one after the other in a consecutive manner after each function has finished executing.
which I am not able to do currently.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can wait 1500 milliseconds  = 1.5 second until each iteration to complete like :

```
for(let i=0;i<this.state.createdAtList.length;i++){
  this.props.UserDataDelete(this.state.createdAtList[i],  uniq[i], this.state.toDel[i],    email);
  sleep(1500):
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. but I want them to trigger exactly when one function finishes  the action

Comment: can you post the function which calls this.props.UserDataDelete

Comment: that is the function I have posted on the second code section. thank you

Comment: have you added "asyn " in front of function englobing the for loop ?